# how to put a count or sum to all duplicates and make every unique data has a row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have this table called Table1 with fields subkey, category and frequency. I want to populate the frequency by counting per category.

| Subkey | Category | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | apple |  |
| BB | apple |  |
| CC | banana |  |
| BB | grapes |  |
| AA | apple |  |
| AA | banana |  |
| CC | banana |  |
| BB | grapes |  |
| AA | apple |  |

I want to achieve this output

| Subkey | Category | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | apple | 3 |
| AA | banana | 1 |
| BB | apple | 1 |
| BB | grapes | 2 |
| CC | banana | 2 |

My code is

```
 SELECT
 DISTINCT a.Category,
          a.Subkey,
      SUM(Case when a.Category    = 'apple'  then 1 
          when a.Category    = 'banana' then 1
          when a.Category    = 'grapes' then 1
 
 else 0 end) AS Frequency

 FROM Table1 as a
 Group BY Category, Subkey
```

I can't seem to have this output. Can you help me? My sql is based on MS SQL Server 2005 capabilities. The only supported operation is the SELECT statement.

Comment: *"My sql is based on MS SQL Server 2005 capabilities."* Are you saying you are using SQL Server 2005 here?

Comment: I don't see why you need a `CASE` here. Why not just `COUNT(Category`)? Why are you  using `DISTINCT` when your data is already in *distinct groups* due to the `GROUP BY`? Having both a `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in the same scope is always the sign of a flaw.

Comment: My work uses SQL marketing cloud. And from the resource I found sir, it uses SQL server 2005 or I'm not sure enough. But the only supported operation is the SELECT statement sir.

Comment: *"it uses SQL server 2005"* SQL Server 2005 hasn't been supported for about **8 years**; it is *long* past time that your business upgraded.

Comment: select t.Subkey,t.Category, count(*)freq from your_table as t group by t.Subkey,t.Category    May be you need this ?

Comment: apologies for I'm not sure the classification of the SQL sir. But the only syntax it reads starts from select sir.

Comment: To extend on other sentiments: the reason it's so bad to use a SQL Server version that hasn't been supported in 8 years is **it hasn't received any security patches in that time**. That is, this is dangerous and unsafe... the kind of thing that **causes a data breach** and eventually gets a company sued out of existence. In other words, your job and livelihood are at stake here. While you may not have the ability to make the change, you can make it an issue with a supervisor, so they can make it an issue for their supervisor, so this can be FIXED (because it really is **broken** right now).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm missing something but why not:

```sql
select Subkey, Category ,COUNT(*)
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY SubKey, Category
```

or if you want to update some column:

```sql
UPDATE  t
SET frequency = x.frequency
FROM    table1 t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  COUNT(*) AS frequency
    ,   subkey, category
    FROM    table1 t2
    GROUP BY subkey, category
    ) x
    ON  x.subkey = t.subkey
    AND x.category = t.category
```